# How get the initial value from Qml Checkbox to c++?

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have qtquick frontend and c++ backend. In Qml I have a checkbox with random initial value. I have a signal emitted onCheckedChanged which is never received. I believe, it is because the component is created before connect statements are made. When user interacts, I can catch those events but I miss the initial value. I cannot make the connections sooner because the QMl engine has to first create the components so I can have a reference to them to make the signal slot connection. So how to find out the initial value? Do I have to make a timer which will emit the value few seconds after startup? Is there a better way?

here is minimum example (when the initial value is true, the slot is never triggered)

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    signal checkboxStateChanged(enabled: bool)
    CheckBox{
        checked: Math.random() > 0.5
        text: "value"
        onCheckedChanged: checkboxStateChanged(checked)
    }
}
```

backend.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
class Backend: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Backend(){}
public slots:
    void logChecked(bool checked){
        qDebug()<<checked;
    }
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QObject>
#include "backend.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);
    const auto root=engine.rootObjects();
    QObject *window = root[0];
    Backend b;
    QObject::connect(window,SIGNAL(checkboxStateChanged(bool)),
                     &b,SLOT(logChecked(bool)));
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: You could wait for `Component.onCompleted` to know if the checkbox has been created.

Comment: Component.onCompleted does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the approach you are trying but a cleaner method would be to bind the QML checked value to the c++ class. Then you can handle everything in your backend class which is a lot easier to debug and maintain. So using your example,

```cpp
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
class Backend: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    // Add a Q_PROPERTY to bind in QML
    Q_PROPERY(Qt::CheckState checked READ getChecked WRITE setChecked NOTIFY checkedChanged)
signals:
    void checkedChanged();
public:
    Backend() { m_checked = <random_value>;}

    // implement the q_property methods
    void setChecked(const Qt::CheckState value) {
        if (m_checked != value) {
             m_checked = value;
             emit checkedChanged();
        }
    }
    Qt::CheckState getChecked() const { return m_checked; }
public slots:
    void logChecked(bool checked){
        qDebug()<<checked;
    }

private:
   m_checked;
};
```

Then in QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQml 2.12 // Binding
import Backend 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    signal checkboxStateChanged(enabled: bool)
    
    CheckBox{
        id: qmlCheckBox
        checked: backend.checked // C++ to QML binding
        text: "value" // you can bind this too
    }

    // QML to C++ binding
    Binding {
        target: backend
        property: "checked"
        value: qmlCheckBox.checked
    }
}
```

In main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QObject>
#include "backend.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    // Register backend class for qml
    qmlRegisterType<Backend>("Backend", 1, 0, "Backend");
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("backend", new Backend);


    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);
    
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: thanks,  just one thing, missing brackets, engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty